How many qubits does the Mahadev's classical-verifier-quantum-prover protocol need?
In Mahadev's protocols, the idea is for a classical verifier to use post-quantum cryptography to check a quantum prover. This allows for various tasks from randomness certification to delegated quantum computations.
My question is, what is the number of qubits required for the prover to participate in this game? One can choose the simplest setting from those proposed by Mahadev so that we use the least amount of resources. I believe current machines do not have enough qubits but I'd like to know which part of the protocol is a resource bottleneck in particular that prevents us from demonstrating it on a quantum device?

For proof-of-quantumness or certified randomness, maybe 2000 ancilla qubits are needed for 50 bits of security if Learning-With-Errors were implemented in superposition.
But this depends on the application, and scales polynomially with circuit depth for other applications such as classical verification of decision problems outside of NP.

The resources grow with the particular implementation of the post-quantum protocol that the prover (Peggy) calculates.  Importantly she calculates these in superposition, requiring a good number of ancilla qubits to do the calculation.
Mahadev instantiates her protocol with a Learning-with-Errors (LWE) based trap-door claw-free function - which has the requisite nice "hardcore" properties that she needs.  This LWE is a bottleneck.  Indeed secure LWE-based encryption is kind of challenging to efficiently implement even classically, requiring pretty large key sizes to be competitive with RSA.  This difficulty is compounded when having to implement reversibly in superposition.
Because you mention certifiable randomness, I'd refer to "Efficient Certifiable Randomness from a Single Quantum Device" by Mahadev, Vazirani, and Vidick.  This is similar to the earlier paper "A Cryptographic Test of Quantumness and Certifiable Randomness from a Single Quantum Device" by Brakerski, Christiano, Mahadev, Vazirani, and Vidick.  In that paper, they state:

This proposal seems promising from a practical viewpoint — indeed, even using off-the-shelf bounds for LWE-based cryptography suggests that a protocol providing 50 bits of security could be implemented with a quantum device of around 2000 qubits (see e.g. [LP11]. It would be worth exploring whether there are clever implementations of this scheme that can lead to a protocol in the 200 − 500 qubit
range.  (Emphasis added).

For the proof-of-quantumness protocol mentioned above, I read this as saying that if you wish to have fifty logical qubits of security, you can prepare the uniform superposition over all fifty logical qubits with fifty logical Hadamard gates in a first register $|x\rangle$, and evaluate the trap-door claw-free function $f(x)$ into a second register $|f(x)\rangle$, to prepare $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$.  But you'd need maybe 2000 ancillary qubits to implement $f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is an LWE-based function.
This work on certifiable randomness and proof-of-quantumness involves only a single iteration of the protocol.  But Mahadev relies on this earlier work to provide a protocol for any quantum computing algorithm in "Classical Verification of Quantum Computations".  Here the complexity (number of qubits, etc.) depends on the depth of the circuit and the number of gates in the computation.
In particular, in one of her presentations at the Simons Institute, towards the end of the presentation I think Ron de Wolf asks about the scaling of the classical verification protocol; after some back-and-forth with Vazirani, Vidick, Aharanov and others about whether or not it's linear in the number of gates in the quantum computuation, everyone laughs when Vazirani affirms that at least it's "polynomial", giving a wink-and-a-nod to theoretical computer scientists' fascination with asymptotics at the expense of practical implementation!

Thanks for the answer. Is the creation of a large superposition over all the preimages the issue in the LWE part? Or can one create such superpositions over large sets without too many qubits and something else in the LWE that causes the high qubit requirement?

Thanks I updated my answer.  It's the actual implementation of LWE that's likely challenging and requires a lot of extra ancillary qubits.
